# How to reformat drive with Ubuntu 14 installed

Tags: passphrase

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  Somehow it let me on install to encrypt the drive.  I wrote down this LONG passphrase. Now it won't let me log in unless I have the passphrase.  I have entered it a hundred times, and it won't work.  I tried to re-install with a flash drive, but when I change boot order Linux over-rides it and still comes up with GRUB menu.  I want to use Linux.  I committed an entire computer to it.  Now I can't get in.  HELP!

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the live USB/CD you need to create a new the partition table. To do this open up a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> type in

```
sudo gparted-pkexec
```

Now make sure you have selected the drive that is encrypted, Then click on Device menu and then click on create a partition table then create a msdos partition table. You shoud be fine with installing Ubuntu.